# How do you get value from private properties in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How to access total and currency data from below return data. I need to access its a paypal return data.

```
<?PHP
$amount = $sale->amount;
print_r($amount);
?>

PayPal\Api\Amount Object
(
    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1.25
            [currency] => EUR
            [details] => PayPal\Api\Details Object
                (
                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                        (
                            [subtotal] => 1.25
                        )

                )

        )

);
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to SHOUT AT US

Comment: @RiggsFolly Probably an ex-cobol developer, used to all caps !

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet Hahah Careful there are a lot of us about pretending to be cool dudes now

Comment: Putting everything in caps isn't going to make us understand any better

Comment: They're declared `private`, so you can only access them from _within_ the class.  I'd imagine that the PayPal object has getters for that.

Comment: Indeed, there appears to be [`getCurrency()`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Amount.php#L40) and [`getTotal()`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Amount.php#L65) methods specifically for this.